# What do delegates catch with a parent and embedded view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a view controller (VC1) which has a container view that holds a table view/VC2.

How I can catch things like scrolling in table view (VC2) but from VC1? Can I use delegates?

Also I am implementing a search feature. Do I have to update the embedded VC2 from VC1, is that also done using delegates?

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. Just to reassure you, yes, use `delegates` in your VC1.

Comment: @iosDev82 thank you. I got working with delegates when using different VC's, But I can't get it to work this time when the VC is embedded. Guess I must have done something wrong so I will take a closer look at it

Comment: You will need to hook up the delegate of VC2 in the `prepareForSegue:` method of VC1

Answer (score 0):

> Now I wonder how I can catch things like scrolling in VC2/table view
>   but from VC1?

You can catch scrolling in the same VC (in your case VC2), then relay that information to VC1 via custom protocols and delegates.

**General principle:** You should treat embedded view controllers like any view controller.

For example, when you want to pass data to the parent view controller from the embedded view controller you could relay that via delegates. You would use the `prepeForSegue` method to set the parent view controller as the delegate.

Similarly, when you want to pass data from the parent view controller to the embedded view controller, you can again pass it via the `prepareForSegue` method. This time you set data from the parent view controller to an embedded view controller variable.

These principles are true for passing data and delegating responsibility to other view controllers, and embedded view controllers should be treated the same way.